# How can I check if a JPEG image has layers?

Tags: gimp, layers

So I have received a logo in JPEG format with a white background to be used on a website. That does not look good as the color does not fit well with the header color.

The person who provided me with the logo says that it is possible to separate the logo itself from the background simply by dragging the logo from the background and all the designer shared was this JPEG.

I installed Gimp and tried to do just that by loading it in there, but it does not work as the white background moves with the rest of the logo when I try to move one from the other.

I know of ways in Gimp I can use to separated the background from the logo myself by editing the image but, since the logo has been provided by a graphic designer I would expect that this should have been shared already with a transparent background, in whatever file format which supports layering, as I am not sure JPEG does.

Am I completely off on my assumption? And if so, how can I check if there are layers on the JPEG?

Comment: No JPG file has layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't change the colors of someones logo because it doesn't work on their website. The design of the website should work with the primary logo unless the company is OK with changing the logo.

> in whatever file format which supports layering, as I am not sure JPEG does

JPEG does not support layers. You should ask for the native file that the logo was designed in or sometimes TIFF files can include layers.

> And if so, how can I check if there are layers on the JPEG?

There is no way, there are no layers in a JPEG file. A JPG file will not have a transparent background but you can edit out the background in GIMP. You can ask the person/designer who provided the logo if there is a PNG version of the logo with a transparent background or for the native file the logo was created in.

Comment: thanks very much for that. I probably have not explainged it correctly. The part of what was not fitting with the color of the site was the wite background in the logo, that's is why the owner of the website and logo has asked for my help to change that white background for a transparent one on the logo not understanding that I can't do that from a developer's standpoint(there might be some CSS trick, but that's beyond the point). Thanks again for your answer. It clarified a lot to me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

JPEGs don't have layers, but they can have thumbnails. Its like a second page to the JPEG, I believe you can remove that with exiftool.

You can check with imagemagick if it has a thumbnail and remove it if it does.